# Python linear regression sklearn library and direct math method is giving different R Squared values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to compare results of `Linear regression` prediction using 2 methods. The first from `sklearn` library which yields the following:

```
print(regressor.intercept_)
print(regressor.coef_)
print(regressor.score(X_train, y_train))
```

Results:

> 26816.19224403119 
>   [9345.94244312]
>   0.9381900012894278

The second method is simple math:

```
x_mean = np.mean(X_train)
y_mean = np.mean(y_train)

size = len(X_train)
num = 0
denom = 0
RSquaredNum = 0
RSquaredDenom = 0
for i in range(0, size):
    num += (X_train.iloc[i]-x_mean)*(y_train.iloc[i]-y_mean)
    denom += (X_train.iloc[i]-x_mean)**2

for i in range(0, len(X_test)):
    RSquaredNum += (y_pred[i] - y_mean)**2
    RSquaredDenom += (y_test.iloc[i] - y_mean)**2

ScoreOfSecondMethod = RSquaredNum/RSquaredDenom

slope = num/denom
interception = y_mean - (slope*x_mean)
```

The following code:

```
print(slope, interception)
```

Gave me:

> 9345.942443
>   26816.192244

The only difference is with R Squared in both methods. The first gave 0.97. But the calculated value gave me 0.93.

Is there anything wrong with `ScoreOfSecondMethod` equation ?

Comment: According to the results you posted above, the sklearn regressor.score value = 0.93819, which is quite close to the calculated one of 0.93 so everything seems fine. Where does 0.97 come from?

Comment: Its from the X train